# Site-to-Site VPN between a Cisco router and a Linux box

Tags: cisco, linux-networking, site-to-site-vpn

**SITE A**

- A Cisco router (877W), configured for incoming VPN IPSec client connections
- Some servers, in a 192.168.0.0/24 network

**SITE B**

- A Linux box with a physical NIC and a vpnc client (tun0/30.30.30.20, sent by the Cisco router of Site A), routing is enabled
- Some workstations, in a 192.168.1.0/24 network

**The problem**

While Site B can successfully access the servers of Site A with their LAN address, servers in Site A can only ping the Linux box with his VPN address. They are unable to access the workstations in the 192.168.1.0/24 LAN.

**Cisco router configuration**

```
crypto isakmp policy 1
 encr 3des
 authentication pre-share
 group 2
crypto isakmp client configuration address-pool local dynpool
!
crypto isakmp client configuration group groupxxx
 key xxxx
 pool dynpool
 acl 105
crypto isakmp profile ciscocp-ike-profile-1
   match identity group groupxxx
   client authentication list ciscocp_vpn_xauth_ml_1
   isakmp authorization list ciscocp_vpn_group_ml_1
   client configuration address respond
   virtual-template 2
!
!
crypto ipsec transform-set ESP-3DES-SHA esp-3des esp-sha-hmac
!
crypto ipsec profile CiscoCP_Profile1
 set transform-set ESP-3DES-SHA
 set isakmp-profile ciscocp-ike-profile-1

access-list 10 permit 192.168.1.0 0.0.0.255
access-list 10 permit 30.30.30.0 0.0.0.255
access-list 10 permit 192.168.0.0 0.0.0.255
access-list 105 permit ip 30.30.30.0 0.0.0.255 192.168.0.0 0.0.0.255
access-list 105 permit ip 192.168.0.0 0.0.0.255 30.30.30.0 0.0.0.255
```

Thanks by advance.

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
ip route 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0 30.30.30.20
```

on the cisco router and see if that works.

Edit:

And do you have any kind of NAT in the mix?

Comment: Already tried that, with no success. Yes, there's NAT on the Cisco, some port-forwarding rules and an overload to permit Internet access to servers on Site A.